# JavaFX | FXML doesn't recognize Controller items

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

> Cannot set javafx.scene.control.ListView to field 'ListView_ToDo'.

[image]

But I has already put `@FXML` as the images below:

[image]

Comment: try to add `fx:controller`argument  to your Vbox

Comment: Please [don't post screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), post the actual code as text (and [format it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). Apart from the many reasons why this is better (that are listed in the post I linked), it is actually much, much easier for you to copy and paste your code, than it is for you to go to the trouble of taking screenshots and uploading them.

Comment: Why do your variables start with upper case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an error like the one you mentioned on IntelliJ:

> Cannot set javafx.scene.control.ListView to field 'ListView_ToDo'

it means that the control in your Controller class named with that id *doesn't match* the control in your FXML file.

In your case:

FXML

```
<ListView fx:id="ListView_ToDo" />
```

Controller

```
@FXML ListView ListView_ToDo;
```

seems ok, but if you look at your imports:

FXML

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
```

Controller:

```
import javax.swing.text.html.ListView;
```

They are different and that's why you get the error.

Just make sure you use the JavaFX ListView import.

```
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
```